# QGIS / is there a possibility to add the date of feature creation afterwards?

Tags: qgis

We've recently noticed some shapefiles in our project are missing a creation date. Specifically, simple point features. Meaning, we don't know when we collected the data in the field.

Is there a possibility to extract this information from metadata?

Comment: There is no metadata associated with shapefiles which would track when edits occurred. If you need this information, you need to collect it at the time the feature is edited. At this point you probably need to guess when each feature was created.

Comment: Can you use the file modification date?

Comment: allright thanks for the fast answer. the file modification date has to be good enough then

Comment: Dbf files do have a header for last update.

Answer (score 2):

Shapefile stores the date of the last update into the dbf header. GDAL gives some control on the modification data both when an existing shapefile is opened and when a new one is written.

https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html#open-options

> DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=YYYY-MM-DD: Modification date to write in DBF
> header with year-month-day format. If not specified, current date is
> used.

https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html#layer-creation-options

```
DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=YYYY-MM-DD: Modification date to write in DBF header with year-month-day format. If not specified, current date is used. Note: behavior of past GDAL releases was to write 1995-07-26
```

QGIS shows this metadata in Layer - Properties - Information

Programs may not update the last update header right, but QGIS (and ESRI) should know what to do. The last update metadata does not change when files are just copied and thus it is more reliable than the modification date that is shown by the file system.